# Javascript as debuggable bytecode

Tags: javascript, debugging, coffeescript, clojurescript

There is a rise in languages that output javascript, such as CoffeeScript and ClojureScript. Since javascript will not be going away anytime soon, I presume this pattern of development will continue.

One problem people have is that you write code in one language and debug in another. The same can be said about the relationship between C and assembly, but assembly generated can have debugging metadata embedded so that the C debugger knows how the assembly relates to the C source sode. So for example: the line number that this block of assembly represents.

And now for my question:

Is anyone aware of any similar efforts to allow for debug metadata to be embedded in the resulting javascript from languages such as CoffeeScript and Clojurescript?

As far as I am aware this would require at least a debugger that supports this theoretical metadata.

Comment: At least with CoffeeScript, the compiled JS that you need to debug is still both quite readable and fairly close to the CoffeeScript source. They list that as an advantage.

Comment: I agree the generated code is readable in terms of CoffeeScript, but I would still like to debug the code in CS :) But in the case of ClojureScript the lisp and javascript tend to deviate from each other conceptually

Comment: if anything where to have this, I would be its gonna be something related to Chrome/v8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Firefox and Webkit-based browsers are planning to support debugging for CoffeeScript and other languages that compile to JS: http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/08/debug-languages-on-javascript-vm

Comment: Thanks Trevor, it's interesting stuff, hopefully it will become a cross browser standard one day.